# Add custom value for link_class_list for the classic editor

Tags: tinymce

I want to add custom settings to the editor, for which I am using the [tiny_mce_before_init](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/tiny_mce_before_init/) filter, as following:

```php
function custom_tinymce_settings( $settings ) {
    
    $settings['link_class_list'] = "[
            {title: 'None', value: ''},
            {title: 'Dog', value: 'dog'},
            {title: 'Cat', value: 'cat'}
        ]";

    return $settings;

}

add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', 'theme\act\custom_tinymce_settings' );
```

The added setting comes right from the Tiny docs for v4, see [link_class_list](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs-4x/plugins/link/#link_class_list).

But it's not adding the classes to the link dialog.

Any idea on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: The WordPress editor does not use the TinyMCE link dialog. It has its own.

Answer (score 0):

As Jacob mentioned in the comment, WordPress adds a custom plugin to TinyMCE which uses a native window with extra features, like loading content from WordPress.

The documentation I referenced is for the TinyMCE official link plugin.

You can still use it, all you have to do is replace the *wplink* plugin with the *link* plugin in the TinyMCE settings.